# Not sure/ not sure about?

Tags: grammar

I am still not 100% sure which career I want to choose. Or: I am still not 100% sure about which career I want to choose?

Which sentence is correct and if there's a better way to form this sentence please help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think both sentences are right, but in different contexts and that people use the two phrases interchangeably.

The first **(sure which)** has to do  mainly with the idea of choosing among a group of alternatives you could have been presented or simply are expected to choose. 
The second example **(sure about...)**,  might be considering wider range of **opinions or considerations**, but abstract. An opinion a thought, I mean, the career you might finally want to choose based on someone´s idea. 
One other way to better understand is through these sentences:

If you are not **sure about which** area your information is related to, please select "General". i
Be **sure about which** jail he or she is in.